# GoogleMapsclient NPM errors on client not on server

Tags: meteor, google-maps-api-3

When I run this code on client side instead of server it returns the error. If it is run on the server it works fine. I'm using `meteor`. I'm struggling to find a solution online. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Path: `Code on client`

```
googleMapsClient.geocode({
  address: 'My test address'
}, function(err, response) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(response.json.results);
  }
});
```

Error: `in console`

```
Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Test%20address&key=MYKEY: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be answered by the author of the library [here.](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/issues/59#issuecomment-282595007) It's a good idea to first go through the github issues for a given library in order to find common mistakes. The idea is that the library is supposed to be used on the server side, for the client side use you would use google's API.